# Accordion won't allow links to open

Tags: jquery, accordion

Here's some js that I'm using for an accordion.  When I click an LI, it opens just like it should but the problem is if I have links in that open area, it closes when I try to click them.

How can the LI stay open so I can click the links?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();
    
  $('.accordion-list li').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
    } else {
      $(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      $(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

Here's the accordion html if it's helpful:

```
<ul class="accordion-list">
    <li class="section1 show">
        <h4>Data Sheets</h4>
        <div class="answer">
        <div class="data-sheets">
            <p><a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></p>
            <p><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="section2 show">
        <h4 class="title">Manuals</h4>
        <div class="answer">
        <div class="manuals">
            <p><a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></p>
            <p><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that clicking on the link will also trigger clicking on the li. So you have to fetch the click on the link and stop propagation.

See this fiddle

Sorry first fiddle was empty.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();

  $('.accordion-list li').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
    } else {
      $(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      $(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('a').click(function(event)
  {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log($(this).attr('href'))
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yc6esxv0/

Comment: Claus, thank you SO MUCH!  This works perfectly and I really appreciate your explanation!